# jQuery's .html() displays before JavaScript processed only in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, dom, innerhtml

In most browsers, jQuery's `html()` only seems to replace the content once any JavaScript within the HTML data is processed (and with that update, associated styles), so it's a smooth replacement. In Firefox, the HTML is displayed plainly for a brief period, and then the JavaScript is processed. An example would be running the following in the browser console with a long string of HTML data that includes a script that heavily changes the markup (for example, a jQuery DataTable initialization):

```
$("#some-div").html(data);
console.log("Done");
```

I also tried the following with the same results, where `true` allows scripts to run.

```
$("#some-div").append($.parseHTML(data, document, true));
console.log("Done");
```

Only after this blip of unprocessed HTML flashing, does the `console.log()` line play, meaning jQuery's `html()` and other methods do wait on script processing, but for some reason Firefox displays the content earlier. Why? How might I get similar "processed" behaviour cross-browser?

Comment: can you elaborate your question? It's bit unclear from here:- `Only after this blip .......`. May be an example link is more good to see what actually you are asking

Comment: @Anant I've added some small clarification of that. I just mean HTML shows before styles and scripts do, which doesn't happen in other browsers. The HTML appears instantly styled in other browsers.

Comment: Are you using document.ready?

Comment: which version of firefox do you using? I use firefox too & don't remember ever having issue like this (or maybe I'm not too observant). But for good practice, .html() should be called when all contents are loaded, so after `$(window).on('load',function() { ...`

Comment: I tested my example line in the browser console with a long string of HTML data, and it has this "lag" of processing. Unless there's a way to manually "ready" or "load" an HTML string.

Comment: if lag is there then it will happen in all browser not in one only. Also as others said that you have to apply your jquery code when document is completely rendered.

Comment: Yes, the document is definitely completely rendered before I call this function.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm not sure why Firefox behaves differently than the other browsers in this regard, but I at least have a simple solution for this.

```
$("#some-div").html(data);
scriptsFromData();
console.log("Done");
```

It was possible for me to remove the scripts from the HTML "data" and just call them as a function embedded in the `html()` calling script. This seems to process much more instantaneously in Firefox rather than relying on the scripts in the HTML data to run quickly.

I won't mark this as an answer because it might not always be possible to decouple those scripts, and it'd be interesting to know why Firefox is slow to run scripts appended to the document vs. other browsers.